# My e-mails are blacklisted. Is it my fault or other people on same server?

Tags: email, server, spam, blacklist

I was using https://www.mail-tester.com to check if my email address was on any spam lists.

It came back with 3 positive results (against 25 of the most common).

Does this mean that people marked my *email address* as spam? Or is it the *server* that is marked as spam? (i.e. the server that hosts my website along with many other peoples' websites)

Comment: It is almost impossible to comment. Can you post screenshots of the results? Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the free versions or lower plans of an e-mail provider, there is a chance that your e-mails will go to SPAM. This is because the IP used by the provider to send your e-mails have been shared with other free users who might have been marked by many people as Spam and that reputation is carry forwarded to you because of the same IP.

To tackle this, almost all e-mail providers give you the option of getting a dedicated IP(some provide free dedicated IP with costlier plans).

This way you start from scratch and messages go to the inbox and would be spam for the users who have marked it so. Keep in mind that this doesn't make your e-mails immune to spam filters, if too many people mark you as spam, it would backfire.

Comment: Were the three results from SORBS(last 48 hours), BACKSCATTERER and SORBS (last 28 days)